# Datadog: API Key invalid dropping transaction when installing Datadog agent

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, datadog

I'm trying to install **Datadog** agent for a **Kubernetes** cluster using **Helm**.

This is the **helm command** I'm using for it:

```
helm repo add datadog https://helm.datadoghq.com

helm repo update

helm upgrade --install datadog datadog/datadog \
  --namespace monitoring \
  --create-namespace \
  --atomic \
  --set datadog.apiKey=<MY-DATADOG-API-KEY> \
  --set targetSystem=linux \
  --values values.yaml
```

**Values file**:

```
datadog:
  kubelet:
    host:
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    hostCAPath: /etc/kubernetes/certs/kubeletserver.crt
    tlsVerify: false # Required as of Agent 7.35. See Notes.
```

However, when I run the **liveness probe error with error 500** which shows the error below:

> CLUSTER | ERROR | (pkg/forwarder/transaction/transaction.go:344 in internalProcess) | API Key invalid, dropping transaction for https://orchestrator.datadoghq.com/api/v1/orchestrator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue had to do with the **Datadog Destination Site**. The Destination site for my metrics, traces, and logs is supposed to be `datadoghq.eu`. This is set using the variable `DD_SITE`, and it defaults to `datadoghq.com` if it is not set.

To check what your **Datadog Destination Site** just look at the URL of your Datadog dashboard:

- For US it will be - https://app.datadoghq.com/
- For EU it will be - https://app.datadoghq.eu/

To set this in your helm chart simply do either of the following:

```
helm repo add datadog https://helm.datadoghq.com

helm repo update

helm upgrade --install datadog datadog/datadog \
  --namespace monitoring \
  --create-namespace \
  --atomic \
  --set datadog.apiKey=<MY-DATADOG-API-KEY> \
  --set targetSystem=linux \
  --set datadog.site=datadoghq.eu \
  --values values.yaml
```

OR set it in your values file:

```
datadog:
  site: datadoghq.eu
  kubelet:
    host:
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    hostCAPath: /etc/kubernetes/certs/kubeletserver.crt
    tlsVerify: false # Required as of Agent 7.35. See Notes.
```

**References**:

1. [Datadog Agent Forwarder fails liveness probe when new spot instance joins cluster, causing multiple restarts #1697](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/1697)
2. [DD_SITE Set to us3.datadoghq.com, but process-agent and security-agent Still Try to Connect to non us3 endpoints #9180](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/9180)

Comment: They now have multiple sites even for the US, so you might need to conf DD_SITE even when using one of those.